# how can i save the results as dataframe after using group by

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

```
df =pd.DataFrame({'variable':['sales_a','sales_c','card','sales_b','gender','age'],'type':['continous','continous','categorical','continous','categorical','categorical']})
```

```
df1 =pd.DataFrame({'tpye':['continous','continous','continous','categorical','categorical','categorical'],'variable':['sales_a','sales_c','sales_b','card','gender','age']})
```

i have tried this:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('type'))
```

how can i get df1 from df by using pd.groupby?

Comment: looks like you just need to sort the values based on column `type` , try `df1=df.sort_values('type')` , if not please explain what are you trying to do

Comment: `df.sort_values('type',ascending=False)`

Comment: thanks,sort_values is much better than groupby.@ansev @anky_91